# Hotstrings in ahk override $

Tags: autohotkey

I have this cool little program, but I cannot use hotstrings with it. How can I get hotstrings to work without screwing up the entire program? 
The program is for a prank on my friend who keeps bragging about his typing speed. For each letter you type, there is a 10% chance your letter will be doubled and a 10 percent chance your letter will be deleted.

```
::test::success
$a::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, a
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, a
return

$b::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, b
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, b
return

$c::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, c
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, c
return

$d::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, d
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, d
return

$e::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, e
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, e
return

$f::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, f
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, f
return

$g::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, g
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, g
return

$h::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, h
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, h
return

$i::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, i
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, i
return

$j::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, j
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, j
return

$k::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, k
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, k
return

$l::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, l
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, l
return

$m::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, m
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, m
return

$n::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, n
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, n
return

$o::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, o
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, o
return

$p::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, p
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, p
return

$q::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, q
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, q
return

$r::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, r
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, r
return

$s::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, s
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, s
return

$t::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, t
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, t
return

$u::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, u
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, u
return

$v::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, v
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, v
return

$w::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, w
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, w
return

$x::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, x
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, x
return

$y::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, y
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, y
return

$z::
   rand := Random(0,100)
   if( rand > 10 )
      send, z
   if( rand > 90 )
      send, z
return


Random(min,max)
{
  Random, random, %min%, %max%
  return random
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to chime in and point you to a potentially better solution.

There's a Command called [Input](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Input.htm) that reads every Key pressed and allows you to set an action upon it. Using your description of the "prank" I came up with this little script:

```
 Loop {
        ; Add any Key in {Key} format followed by Period . that you want to act as an EndKey.
        Input, Key, L1 M, {space}.{esc}.{shift}.{enter}
                         .{tab}.{backspace}.{alt}.{home}
                         .{delete}.{pgup}.{pgdn}.{end}
                         .{up}.{down}.{left}.{right}
            If (Key <> "") {
                rand := Random(0,100)
                If (Rand > 90) {
                        Send, %key%
                }
                Send, %key%   
                }
            If InStr(ErrorLevel, "EndKey:") 
                Send % "{" . StrReplace(ErrorLevel, "EndKey:") . "}"
    }
;Took me a second to figure out why your Random Function wasn't working as AHK only has a Random Command ;)
Random(Min := "", Max := "") {
   Random, OutputVar, %Min%, %Max%
   Return OutputVar 
}
```

Comment: This does not compile for me, does it for you?

Comment: This does look a lot more concise than my perl generated script xD though. This answer however useful it may be, does not answer the question of how I can get hotstrings to work with the program.

Comment: Ok, I debugged your code a ton, and I now have this, which still doesn't compile because I don't know the language well enough to debug it.'

Comment: Did you download the Latest Version of Autohotkey from ahkscript.org? if not do so now! And the answer is to use a second script for the hotstrings. since you'll want this code to be hidden by using #NoTrayIcon

Comment: I'm not sure if I can get the latest version as it is an install, and I don't have admin on my windows machine. I most likely downloaded a less recent version that was zipped.also, Is there a way to get the second script to be attached to the first script with out them conflicting? @ahkcoder

Comment: http://ahkscript.org/download/ahk-u32.zip portable zip. Not sure, it's tough to say if there is an effective way... I'd say just try running it running the script separately as it works great with hotstrings. be sure to Hide the script with #NoTrayIcon that way it's undetectable, especially if you compile it and name it SystemMonitor32.exe place it in a Windows Directory or something (looks convincing from the Taskmanager)...

Comment: This download does not include a compiler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90377/discussion-between-ahkcoder-and-10-replies).

Answer (score 0):

By default, [hook](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm) [hotkeys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and [hotstrings](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotstrings.htm) ignore keyboard and mouse events generated by any AutoHotkey script.

In some cases it can be useful to override this behaviour; for instance, to allow a remapped key to be used to trigger other hotkeys. [SendLevel](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SendLevel.htm) and [#InputLevel](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm) provide the means to achieve this.

Comment: Can you suggest how I should implement SendLevel and inputlevel (please dont write the entire code for me, just explain how I would use it and write code for maybe just the letter a, and a hot string) I am having trouble understanding how you can get the hotkeys not to recurse and have them output to hotstrings as well.